# Why use an NSFileManager rather than just using NSData's writeToFile:atomically: method when creating a new file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

Consider the following two code samples:

```
    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgFull);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];   
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"itemImg_%i.png", timestamp]]; //add our image to the path
    [imgData writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];
```

and

```
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgFull);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];   
NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"itemImg_%i.png", timestamp]]; //add our image to the path
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imgData attributes:nil];
```

The second example requires an extra line of code and the initialization of an NSFileManager object, whereas the first example simply has the NSData object `imgData` write itself to a file. An additional advantage of the first example is that it can overwrite a pre-existing file that has the same name.

My question is: when creating new files, under what circumstances would you actually want to use NSFileManager and its method `createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:`?

Comment: NSData's writeToFile doesn't overwrite as default, from my experience. And neither does NSFileManager's createFileAtPath with attributes: nil. Info on the attributes NSDictionary method is forthcoming, suggesting that it's not often used.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The advantage of the `NSFileManager` method is the `attributes` field:

> A dictionary containing the attributes to associate with the new file. You can use these attributes to set the owner and group numbers, file permissions, and modification date. For a list of keys, see “File Attribute Keys.” If you specify nil for attributes, the file is created with a set of default attributes.

This feature is unusual to use on iOS, but `NSFileManager` is much older than iOS.

BTW, the extra line you're describing almost never comes up in real code. Either you already have a `fileManager` variable that you were using for other reasons, or you combine the two lines into one:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imgData attributes:nil];
```

And just one more. As you note:

> An additional advantage of the first example is that it can overwrite a pre-existing file that has the same name.

Well, that's an advantage or a disadvantage depending on what you want. If you mean "create this file, but don't overwrite it if it already exists," then the FM method is much more convenient. Maybe it's an error to overwrite an existing file; this saves you the call to `fileExistsAtPath:`. Maybe you want to create an empty file if it's not there, but leave it alone if it is. Simple: pass `[NSData data]` as the `contents` value.

So which is better depends on what problem you're solving.

Comment: Great answer, and thanks for briefly touching on the broader, non-iOS raison d'etre of the NSFileManager class.

Comment: under SandBox, it's getting more in differ. Hope Rob can upgrade the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

according to my knowledge and after read answer by Rob,Most file operations can be performed using the shared file manager object. because every path generate only once.So can not arise override situation.Please correct if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have found that `writeToFile:atomically:` doesn't fit well when unit testing the code. To make testing comfortable I had to inject `NSFileManager` into the class and in test I have used mocked file manager to verify behavior.